Is there a command equivalent to `git checkout --theirs` and `git checkout --ours` with `git reset`?
I prefer to use other commands than git checkout because of the ambiguity of git checkout; I prefer to use git reset (and git switch for branches).
However, I have noticed that I don't know how to do git checkout --theirs <file> and git checkout --ours <file> during rebase without using checkout.
Is there an alternative git command that is equivalent to git checkout --theirs / git checkout --ours?

Ah I confused reset and restore.
git restore --theirs/git restore --ours works as it should.
